# How to precisely mimic on-prem Hadoop configurations to GCP Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Dataproc is a kind of Apache-Hadoop De-Facto on GCP. I need some clarity in terms on Cluster configurations. Suppose, I have 1-namenode and n-number of datanodes configured with on-prem Hadoop cluster. Do I need to have 1-master node and n-number of worker nodes corresponding to them on Dataproc. I also want to leverage auto-scaling feature of Dataproc.
Do we have any standard checklist which is needed to be followed while migrating an on-prem Hadoop infrastructure to GCP Dataproc?

Comment: If you want auto-scaling then you aren't "precisely mimicing", you're just setting up a new cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no requirement that your Dataproc cluster exactly match your on-prem configuration: in fact, one of the advantages of Dataproc is that you can rescale clusters as needed to match your workloads.

GCP has a [detailed guide](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migration/hadoop/hadoop-gcp-migration-overview) available for migrating on-prem Hadoop to Dataproc.